# facebook login is not working in all android device

Tags: android, facebook

Hello Friends I implemented login by facebook account , in my android application ,but the problem is this functionality is not working in all mobiles like if i am running application in 2.2 mobile its working fine but when i tried in HTC Mobile which is haveing 2.3 version login page is coming and suddenly disappearing .

```
public class TestLoginListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        testAuthenticatedApi();
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
    }
}

public boolean testAuthenticatedApi() {

  if (!authenticatedFacebook.isSessionValid()) return false;
  try {
      Log.d("Tests", "Testing request for 'me'");
      String response1 = authenticatedFacebook.request("me")

      JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response1);

      fbid=obj.getString("id");
      String name=obj.getString("name");
      fbfirstname=obj.getString("first_name");
      fblastname=obj.getString("last_name");
      fbemail=obj.getString("email");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think I know the cause. I've hacked around with implementing facebook and what you are describing usually happens if your device already has a facebook app installed and you are logged in currently. Then when you try logging in, it just shows the login for a brief moment before disappearing. I'm guessing your HTC has the fb app and somebody is logged in while your other mobiles do not have the fb app installed. I think this happens because the fb server is not pinged when you try logging in. It pings the fb app instead.

The solution I came up with was to change the code to NOT use SSO (Single Sign On). I'm sure others would disagree with this approach, but I chose not to use SSO and it works fine. To do this, use `authorize(FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH)`.

I did some digging around and found a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679875/is-there-a-way-to-log-out-via-facebook-api-on-android-if-you-have-the-facebook-a) question.